# How to select specific element form list by using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium

Can anyone guide me how to select specific element from list view
from using below code.

```
<div id="menu" class="tabalign k-widget k-reset k-header k-menu k-menu-horizontal" data-role="menu" tabindex="0" role="menubar" aria-activedescendant="menu_mn_active">
<li class="k-item k-state-default k-first mainMenu2" role="menuitem" id="menu_mn_active"><span class="k-link"><img class="k-image" alt="" src="/Images/Common/Module_2.png"><span id="2">Profiles</span></span></li>
<li class="k-item k-state-default mainMenu3" role="menuitem"><span class="k-link"><img class="k-image" alt="" src="/Images/Common/Module_3.png"><span id="3">Contacts</span></span></li>
```

And I have tried below code but it is not worked for me:

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu_mn_active\"]"));
 element.click();
```

Comment: What do you mean by `not worked for me`? Did you face any error? What does the error says? Can you update the Question with your Software Configuration (Selenium/WebDriver/Browser versions) and error stack  trace?

Comment: Update the question with which element you are trying to select/click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in Java (it selects first element from dropdown):

```
driver.findElement(By. id("menu")).click();

List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By. cssSelector(".k-item.k-state-default"));

for (WebElement opt : options) {

    if (opt.getText().equals("Profiles")) {

        opt.click();

    }

}
```

Comment: hi,
i have tried with your code like below ,but it is displaying red mark to click function.

                String []aelements = {"profiles","contacts"};
      
       WebElement elements =  (WebElement) driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".k-item.k-state-default"));
       aelements[0].click();

Comment: @Akhil, I have changed my answer -- try again, please.

Comment: i am using java code ,can you please suggest me in java

Comment: @Akhil, I have translated the code to the Java language. Try on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

First get location of all elements:

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu_mn_active\"]"));
```

For the first element:

```
element.get(0).click(); // for first element
```

For the second element:

```
element.get(1).click(); // for second element
```

Comment: Hi ,
it is showing red underline for List,when i copy and paste  , is there any import statment for list

Comment: Import Util package

Comment: Error in the sence ,it is showing red underline below 'List'

Comment: Ok Press Control+shift+o and import util package

Comment: Ok ,it is fine ....But element click event is not working while excuting